# Cascade Delete in Dynamic Realm

Tags: android, dynamic, realm, cascade, cascading-deletes

Actually, I was trying to delete an entry from a table(Parent Table) and along with that, I wanted to delete all entries from all table(Child Tables) associated with that parent table. But the problem is that Dynamic Realm Does not support Cascade Delete. So the question is that how can we cascade delete in Dynamic Realm?

My Approach was Recursion. But I am open to other alternatives.

```
    public void cascadeDelete (DynamicRealmObject dynamicObj){
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        DynamicRealm dynamicRealm =
                DynamicRealm.getInstance(realm.getConfiguration());
        try {
            String fieldNames[] = dynamicObj.getFieldNames();
            for(String field : fieldNames) {
                if(dynamicObj.getFieldType(field).equals(RealmFieldType.LIST)) {
                    List<DynamicRealmObject> dynamicRealmObjects =
                            dynamicObj.getList(field);
                    List<DynamicRealmObject> newList = new RealmList<>();
                    newList.addAll(dynamicRealmObjects);
                    for(int k = 0; k < newList.size(); k++) {
                        String primaryKey =
                                Objects.requireNonNull(dynamicRealm.getSchema().get(field))
                                        .getPrimaryKey();
                        String primaryId =
                                Objects.requireNonNull(newList.get(k)).getString(primaryKey);
                        DynamicRealmObject filterObj =
                                dynamicRealm.where(field).equalTo(primaryKey,
                                                                  primaryId).findFirst();
                        if(filterObj != null) {
                            cascadeDelete(filterObj);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dynamicRealm.beginTransaction();
            dynamicObj.deleteFromRealm();
            dynamicRealm.commitTransaction();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            dynamicRealm.close();
            realm.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So my approach is using Recursion. but I am open to other alternatives.

Comment: Could you show us what you have been trying to do so far?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my Question. Please take a look.